# jQuery validation fails on change for a specific set values

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I am facing a strange validation error while checking marks from a student marks input field.

Input `id` is keeping the max marks to compare with the entered values(in current case its 35). So if a user enters value less than 35 or 35 its acceptable but not greater than 35..but in the current case its breaking for 100 and greater values.

keeping it simple and short, my `HTML` goes like this -

```
<input type="text" value="30" id="studentname[98989898][marks-35_compid-1_subid-12]" name="studentname[98989898][marks-35_compid-1_subid-12]" style="width:50px;text-align:center">
```

My **jQuery** code -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery("input[type='text']").on('change', function(event) {
      var colId = event.target.id;
      var maxMarksSplit=colId.split("marks-");
      var maxMarks = maxMarksSplit[1].split("_compid"); 
      alert("Max marks " + maxMarks[0] );
      if( jQuery(this).val() > maxMarks[0] )
      {
      alert("Please check your value!" );
      jQuery(this).val(0);
      }
      });
});
```

Working fiddle **DEMO** --> http://jsfiddle.net/swapnesh/ktKE3/

Test pass for values less than `100` but it fails for values greater than or equal to `100`.

Let me know about this strange validation behavior and what I am doing wrong logically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"parseFloat" may be helpful

try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("input[type='text']").on('change', function(event) {
  var colId = event.target.id;
  var maxMarksSplit=colId.split("marks-");
  var maxMarks = maxMarksSplit[1].split("_compid"); 
  alert("Max marks " + maxMarks[0] );
  if( parseFloat(jQuery(this).val()) > parseFloat(maxMarks))
  {
  alert("Please check your value!" );
  jQuery(this).val(0);
  }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for being the first and accurate +1 and green tick :)

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing to the wrong value. maxMarks is the split array, you want to compare to maxMarks[0].

Also, you need to parse the inputs as they'll both be pulled as strings:

```
  jQuery("input[type='text']").on('change', function(event) {
  var colId = event.target.id;
  var maxMarksSplit=colId.split("marks-");
  var maxMarks = maxMarksSplit[1].split("_compid"); 
  alert("Max marks " + maxMarks[0] );
  if( parseInt(jQuery(this).val()) + parseInt(maxMarks[0]) )
  {
      alert("Please check your value!" );
      jQuery(this).val(0);
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is located in your comparison, you compare your value with maxMarks instead of maxMarks[0]

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("input[type='text']").on('change', function(event) {
  var colId = event.target.id;
  var maxMarksSplit=colId.split("marks-");
  var maxMarks = maxMarksSplit[1].split("_compid"); 
  alert("Max marks " + maxMarks[0] );
  if( jQuery(this).val() > parseInt(maxMarks[0]) ) // Here the modification
  {
  alert("Please check your value!" );
  jQuery(this).val(0);
  }
  });
```

});

Comment: Sorry it was a typo..although it is still not working.. +1 for parseInt